# Cannot Change Accent Color for WASM on Uno 2.4

Tags: c#, uwp, wasm-bindgen, uno-platform

I defined a new accent color in App.xaml lke this:

```
Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">#FFCB2128</Color>
            <Color x:Key="AcmGreen">#FFB8C282</Color>
            <Color x:Key="AcmPink">#FFE672A4</Color>
            <Color x:Key="AcmPurple">#FF71749E</Color>
            <Thickness x:Key="PivotItemMargin">0</Thickness>

        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
```

It works on UWP app:

[image]

However, Accent Color stays default blue on WASM Page (Edge Chromium - 81.0.416.77)

[image]

The accent color on WASM do not match with UWP version which defined in App.xaml. It should be. How can I fix this?

Nuget Package:

Package Version(s):

- Uno.UI.RemoteControl {2.4.0}
- Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap {1.2.0}
- Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.DevServer {1.2.0}
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter {1.1.2}
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Con... {1.1.1}
- NETStandard.Library {2.0.3}
- Uno.UI {2.4.0}
- Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindo... {6.2.10}
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Con... {1.1.1}
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter {1.1.2}
- Microsoft.UI.Xaml {2.4.0}
- Uno.Core {2.0.0}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globally modifying theme colors this way will be supported in Uno soon, when [this PR is merged](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/pull/1766).

For now if you want to modify the color scheme with Uno, you will need to do it per control. For instance for `ToggleSwitch` you would:

1. Copy the [style for ToggleSwitch](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/589f030d38025a4ff8344c53bd72a328e2667c87/src/Uno.UI/UI/Xaml/Style/Generic/Generic.xaml#L5293-L5671) into a `ResourceDictionary` file in your app (typically into a standalone file called `ToggleSwitch.xaml`).
2. Include it in `Application.Resources` in `App.xaml`
3. Modify the part of the style that sets the toggle switch's background. (It looks like [this line](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/589f030d38025a4ff8344c53bd72a328e2667c87/src/Uno.UI/UI/Xaml/Style/Generic/Generic.xaml#L5634): `Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}"`)