# Customizing Style of WinUI ProgressRing Not Available on WASM with Uno 2.4

Tags: c#, uwp, wasm-bindgen, uno-platform, winui

I know globally modifying theme colors with template binding way [not supported in Uno yet.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61889917/cannot-change-accent-color-for-wasm-on-uno-2-4) (I tried it for ToggleSwitch, now ToggleSwitch custom style runs perfectly both on UWP and WASM). So, I prepared a custom style for WinUI 2.4 ProgressRing in a same way. I gathered the default style of ProgressRing from WinUI Github repo and customize it:

```
 <!-- Default style for Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.ProgressRing -->
            <Style x:Key="AcmProgressRing" TargetType="controls:ProgressRing">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource AcmPink}" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource AcmPurple}" />
                <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="16" />
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="16" />
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="32" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:ProgressRing">
                            <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Active">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0:0:0.15" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Inactive">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="0"
                                            Duration="0" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <!-- AnimatedVisualPlayer for Lottie -->
                                <controls:AnimatedVisualPlayer x:Name="IndeterminateAnimatedVisualPlayer" AutoPlay="false" Stretch="fill"/>

                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

My ProgressRing is:

```
<controls:ProgressRing x:Name="Waiter" Width="50" Height="50" Style="{StaticResource AcmProgressRing}" IsActive="True"/>
```

As you see, the style runs correctly on UWP:
[image]

However, WASM shows default style :(

[image]

Packages

```
  - Uno.UI.RemoteControl {2.4.0}

  - Newtonsoft.Json {12.0.3}

  - Uno.UI.Lottie {2.4.0}

  - Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap {1.2.0}

  - Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.DevServer {1.2.0}

  - ACM_Search_AdminApps.Shared {1.1.0}

  - Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter {1.1.2}

  - Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Con... {1.1.1}

  - NETStandard.Library {2.0.3}

   - Uno.UI {2.4.0}

   - ACM_Search_AdminApps.Shared {1.1.0}

  - Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindo... {6.2.10}

   - Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Con... {1.1.1}

  - Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter {1.1.2}

  - Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie {6.0.0}

  - Microsoft.UI.Xaml {2.4.2}

   - Newtonsoft.Json {12.0.3}

  - Uno.Core {2.0.0}
```

WinUI ProgressRing's style on WASM must match with UWP style. How can I fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: Where did you place you default style ?

Comment: In App.xaml  :) @JeromeLaban

Comment: Can you try creating another resource dictionary, and place the default style there, and reference it from the App.xaml ? It's probably something that will be fixed by https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/pull/1766

Comment: Sure, I will try it and inform you. @JeromeLaban

Comment: Same issue again. So I decided to use custom Lottie animation instead of ProgressRing. However, a different Javascript issue on Uno.Lottie prevents me to using on WASM. Maybe, it causes both ProgressRing  animation and theme issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62030326/uncaught-type-javascript-error-in-uno-lottie-webassembly?noredirect=1#comment109740278_62030326

Comment: Changing variables (colors) of a Lottie animation is not supported yet on Uno.UI.Lottie.