# Uncaught Type JavaScript Error In Uno.Lottie WebAssembly

Tags: javascript, c#, uwp, lottie, uno-platform

I have an AnimatedVisualPlayer on my Page for playing a Lottie:

```
<winui:AnimatedVisualPlayer
    x:Name="player"
    AutoPlay="true" Width="150" Height ="150" PlaybackRate="1.5">

    <lottie:LottieVisualSource
        UriSource="ms-appx:///Lottie/waiter.json" />
</winui:AnimatedVisualPlayer>
```

I installed these packages:

- Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie (for theLottieVisualSource)

  - Microsoft.UI.Xaml (for the AnimatedVisualPlayer)
  - Uno.UI.Lottie (for the LottieVisualSource)
  - Uno.UI (for the AnimatedVisualPlayer)

I did it also:

> On WASM, iOS and macOS, you can put the Lottie .json files directly in
>   a folder of the shared project (for example "Lottie/myanimation.json")
>   and set their Build action as Content.

UWP can play the Lottie seamlessly:

[image]

However, WASM cannot play Lottie with this error:

[image]

[image: Error 55]

**Nuget Package Version(s):**

Nuget Package:

Package Version(s):

- Uno.UI.RemoteControl {2.4.0}
- Newtonsoft.Json {12.0.3}
- Uno.UI.Lottie {2.4.0}
- Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap {1.2.0}
- Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.DevServer {1.2.0}
- ACM_Search_AdminApps.Shared {1.1.0}
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter {1.1.2}
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Con... {1.1.1}
- NETStandard.Library {2.0.3}
- Uno.UI {2.4.0}
- ACM_Search_AdminApps.Shared {1.1.0}
- Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindo... {6.2.10}
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Con... {1.1.1}
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter {1.1.2}
- Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie {6.0.0}
- Microsoft.UI.Xaml {2.4.2}
- Newtonsoft.Json {12.0.3}
- Uno.Core {2.0.0}
- Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie {6.0.0}

How can I fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: It seems you found a bug :-).  Le me try on my side. Do you have repro code you can share?

Comment: Sure. I sent it a copy via GitHub collaborate invite. @CarldeBilly

Comment: Errors: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'animation' of undefined" executing javascript: "Uno.UI.Lottie.pause(403458);"  AND dotnet.js:1 Error #1 "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'" executing javascript: "Uno.UI.Lottie.setAnimationProperties({elementId:282194,jsonPath:"/Lottie/waiter.json",autoplay:true,stretch:"Uniform",rate:1,5});"  .  Maybe a little "}" causes a problem  @carldebilly ?

Comment: I'm checking it right now. Thanks for the repro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the Lottie add-in for Uno-Wasm, caused by the fact you were using the `PlaybackRate` and you're running in a non-english context with a culture where the decimal are serialized using a comma and not a dot.

[This PR #3257](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/pull/3257) should fix the problem.

**UPDATE**: This PR has been merged and the fix will be available in [Uno v`3.0.0-dev.135`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uno.UI/3.0.0-dev.135).

Comment: Yep. I can confirm that, it is working after removing the playback rate.